# Ruby - Understanding Winning Method

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby code here that has two series of hashes and there is the method.

```
VALID_CHOICES = {
  'r' => 'rock',
  'p' => 'paper',
  'sc' => 'scissors',
  'l' => 'lizard',
  'sp' => 'spock'
}

WINNING_COMBO = {
  'r' => ['sc', 'l'],
  'p' => ['r', 'sp'],
  'sc' => ['p', 'l'],
  'l' => ['sp', 'p'],
  'sp' => ['sc', 'r']
}

def win?(first, second)
  WINNING_COMBO[first].include?(second)
end
```

Any one out there that can explain me what this win? method does? And is it similar to this?

```
def win?(first, second)
  (first == 'sc' && second == 'p') ||
    (first == 'p' && second == 'r') ||
    (first == 'r' && second == 'l') ||
    (first == 'l' && second == 'sp') ||
    (first == 'sp' && second == 'sc') ||
    (first == 'sc' && second == 'l') ||
    (first == 'l' && second == 'p') ||
    (first == 'p' && second == 'sp') ||
    (first == 'sp' && second == 'r') ||
    (first == 'r' && second == 'sc')
end
```

I hope I can get an explanation in layman's term or in a way a dummy can understand for that method. Sorry dummy here. I would really need your ideas. Thanks so much! Hope you understand.

Comment: _"And is it similar to this?"_ – write a [test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) to ensure that `win?` is working as expected. And whenever possible, write that [test first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This first part `WINNING_COMBO[first]` looks up one of the entries in `WINNING_COMBO`. For example if `first` is "r" then this would return the array `['sc', 'l']`:

```
WINNING_COMBO['r']
#=> ["sc", "l"]
```

...we then check if that array contains the value of `second` so for the values "sc" or "l" this would be true:

```
WINNING_COMBO['r'].include?('sc')
#=> true

WINNING_COMBO['r'].include?('l')
#=> true
```

This is equivalent to the longer `win?` method with all the winning combinations listed out as individual conditions.